# How to fix background color overlapping dialog box?

Tags: android, android-alertdialog

I have added a dialog box like in this answer How to show a dialog to confirm that the user wishes to exit an Android Activity?

But when I implemented it,the background color of the activity clouds the dialog box.Does anyone have a solution to this problem as I can't see any obvious reason? I'm thinking there might be a way to fix this by editing the dialog box background settings?[image: color ooverlapping dialog box]

This is the snippet where I add the dialog box to the main activity:

```
public void onBackPressed() {
        new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
            .setIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_alert)
            .setTitle("Closing Activity")
            .setMessage("Are you sure you want to close this activity?")
            .setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                finish();    
            }

        })
        .setNegativeButton("No", null)
        .show();
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `AlertBox` normally uses the layout of current activity since you specify `this`

Check this http://www.androidpeople.com/android-custom-dialog-example

another one http://android-codes-examples.blogspot.in/2011/04/animated-customized-popup-transparent.html